# Is there a way to unpack a config file to cli flags in general?

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, zsh

Basically what `foo(**bar)` does in python, here I’d want something like

```
foo **bar.yaml
```

and that would become

```
foo --bar1=1 --bar2=2
```

Where `bar.yaml` would be

```
bar1: 1
bar2: 2
```

Comment: The big difference is that Python knows about its own `dict` format and keyword-argument passing. `bash` doesn't know about YAML *or* the options that `foo` accepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a combination of `sed` and `xargs`:

```
sed -E 's/^(.+):[[:space:]]+(.+)$/--\1=\2/' bar.yaml | xargs -d '\n' foo
```

`sed` converts the format of `bar.yaml` lines (e.g. `bar1: 1` -> `--bar1=1`) and `xargs` feeds the converted lines as arguments to `foo`.

You could of course modify/extend the `sed` part to support other formats or single-dash options like `-v`.

---

To test if this does what you want, you can run this Bash script instead of `foo`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Arguments: $#"
for ((i=1; i <= $#; i++)); do
    echo "Argument $i: '${!i}'"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version for `zsh`.  Run this code or add it to `~/.zshrc`:

```
function _yamlExpand {
    setopt local_options extended_glob

    # 'words' array contains the current command line
    # yaml filename is the last value
    yamlFile=${words[-1]}

    # parse 'key : value' lines from file, create associative array
    typeset -A parms=("${(@s.:.)${(f)"$(<${yamlFile})"}}")

    # trim leading and trailing whitespace from keys and values
    # requires extended_glob
    parms=("${(kv@)${(kv@)parms##[[:space:]]##}%%[[:space:]]##}")

    # add -- and = to create flags
    typeset -a flags
    for key val in "${(@kv)parms}"; do
        flags+=("--${key}='${val}'")
    done

    # replace the value on the command line
    compadd -QU -- "$flags"
}

# add the function as a completion and map it to ctrl-y
compdef -k _yamlExpand expand-or-complete '^Y'
```

At the `zsh` shell prompt, type in the command and the yaml file name:

```
% print -l -- ./bar.yaml▃
```

With the cursor immediately after the yaml file name, hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>. The yaml filename will be replaced with the expanded parameters:

```
% print -l -- --bar1='1' --bar2='2' ▃
```

Now you're set;  you can hit enter, or add parameters, just like any other command line.

---

Notes:

- This only supports the `yaml` subset in your example.
- You can add more `yaml` parsing to the function, possibly with `yq`.
- In this version, the cursor must be next to the `yaml` filename - otherwise the last value in `words` will be empty. You can add code to detect that case and then alter the `words` array with `compset -n`.
- `compadd` and `compset` are described in the `zshcompwid` man page.
- `zshcompsys` has details on `compdef`; the section on autoloaded files describes another way to deploy something like this.